# Share binding between two ViewModels in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, mvvm

I just got started with SwiftUI and I would like to use ViewModels to encapsulate my logic, and separate it from my Views.

Now I just hit my first roadblock and I am not sure how to get passed this.

So my app so far is fairly simple. I have two Views, each with their own ViewModels: `Parent` and `Child`.

The `Parent` ViewModel holds a list of `Item`s, which are fetched from a backend API. I want to pass this to `Child` and its ViewModel, since it is responsible for adding `Item`s to the list.

Here's the simplified code for this:

```swift
struct ParentView: View {
  @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      ChildView()
      Text("Items: \(viewModel.items.count)")
    }
  }
}

extension ParentView {
  @MainActor class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item] = []
  }
}

struct ChildView: View {
  @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(viewModel.items) { item in
        Text(item.name)
      }
    }
    .toolbar {
      ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
        Button {
          viewModel.AddItem()
        } label: {
          Label("Add item", systemImage: "plus")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

extension ChildView {
  @MainActor class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item] = []
    func AddItem() {
      items.append(Item(name: "Test"))
    }
  }
}
```

How can I make it so that the list of items from the parent view model is passed down to the view model of the child, ensuring that there is only a single list, while also making sure that both views get refreshed when this list changes?

Thanks!

Comment: You move the lists down to manager/store that both view models can access independently. View models have no reason to know anything about each other.

Comment: Why using `@StateObject` instead of `@State` when you don't need a reference type? A lot of extra work for nothing.

Comment: yes you can easily do without the ViewModel, but that is not what the question is about: 
`...I would like to use ViewModels to encapsulate my logic, and separate it from my Views...`. The OP is just starting with SwiftUI and would like to learn how to use ViewModels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must only have **one source of truth**, in your `ParentView` that you then pass to the child views. Currently you have multiple `ViewModel` that have no relations to each other.

In `ChildView` replace  `@StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()` with
`@ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel`, and in `ParentView`,
use `ChildView(viewModel: viewModel)` to pass the `ViewModel` to it.

Remove also `extension ChildView ...` and take `@MainActor class ViewModel: ObservableObject` out of the `extension ParentView`.

Have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to use `ObservableObject` and manage data in your app https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

EDIT-1:

Here is my full test example code to show how the parent view model
is passed down to the child view `...ensuring that there is only a single list, while also making sure that both views get refreshed when this list changes`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack { // <-- here
            ParentView()
        }
    }
}

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name:String
}

struct ParentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel() // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ChildView(viewModel: viewModel)  // <-- here
            Text("Items: \(viewModel.items.count)")
        }
    }
}

// -- here
@MainActor class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item] = [Item(name: "item-1"), Item(name: "item-2")]
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.items) { item in
                Text(item.name)
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button {
                    viewModel.items.append(Item(name: "Test")) // <-- here
                } label: {
                    Label("Add item", systemImage: "plus")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```